# WordPress menu click

Tags: wordpress, menu, toggle

I have a website http://buluttextile.uz/. When the size is less than 768px when you press the button the menu opens and quickly disappears. Why does not he stay? Can someone help me? The site is created on Wordpress. Several plug-ins have been installed: Meta Slider, NextGEN Gallery, Huge IT Slider, Tabs Responsive.

Comment: The issue can be caused by several things:

1) Cache optimization
2) Custom CSS plugins
3) Cookie Law plugins
4) Custom JS plugins
5) CSS/JS minifier
6) etc...

Try disabling (not uninstalling) the plugins one at a time and see if something changes.

Was your theme working properly when you installed it?

Comment: Did you check my code, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this style `height: 1px;`

```
#site-navigation {
     height: 1px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 1px;` from your active theme [style.css](http://buluttextile.uz/wp-content/themes/buluttextil/style.css?ver=v1)

```
#site-navigation {  // Line no 1478
     height: 1px;    
}
```